# How to get rid of comma (,) when echo values from array in php

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, ajax

i am sending data from multiple checkboxes via ajax to php.
This is the html:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="get_value" value="PHP" />PHP <br />  
<input type="checkbox" class="get_value" value="ASP" />ASP <br />  
<input type="checkbox" class="get_value" value="JSP" />JSP <br />  
<input type="checkbox" class="get_value" value="Python" />Python <br />                      

<button type="button" name="submit" class="btn btn-info submit">Submit</button>
```

The js:

```
$(document).on('click' , '.submit' , function() { 

    var languages = [];  
    $('.get_value').each(function(){  
        if($(this).is(":checked"))  
            {  
                 languages.push($(this).val());  
            }  
    });  
    languages = languages.toString();  
    $.ajax({  
        url:"",  
        method:"POST",  
        data:{languages:languages},  
        success:function(data){  
                $('#result').html(data);  
        }  
    }); 

});
```

And the php:

```
if(isset($_POST["languages"]))  { 
    $checkboxfiles[] = $_POST["languages"]; 
    foreach ($checkboxfiles as $checkboxfile) {
        echo $checkboxfile.'<br />';
    }   
    exit;            
}
```

When checking 3 checkboxes, the echo gives me an output like this: `PHP,ASP,JSP`

How can i get rid of the comma and make an echo like this:

`PHP
ASP
JSP`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it is a comma separated string, you could [explode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) on a comma and loop the values

```
foreach ($checkboxfiles as $checkboxfile) {
    foreach(explode(',', $checkboxfile) as $value) {
        echo $value.'<br />';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace the komma with `<br>` if in `HTML` otherwise you could use `\n`. Notice: you have to use double quotes `"` if you need to use `\n`

```
if(isset($_POST["languages"]))  { 
    $checkboxfiles[] = $_POST["languages"]; 

    foreach ($checkboxfiles as $checkboxfile)
    {
        echo str_replace(',', '<br>', $checkboxfile) . '<br>';
    }             
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to add this in the foreach loop:

```
$checkboxfile = str_replace(',', '', $checkboxfile);
```